# Use div's height to determine another div's padding or margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I am using the following jQuery to work out the width of a div (thats in %), to then tell another div to set it's height to that in pixels.

```
<script>
    $("#top").height($("#left").width());
    $("#bottom").height($("#left").width());
</script>
```

It's working really well. Now my next problem is, that I want my div called 'wrapper' to have a padding-top or margin-top of the pixel value it returns for the height. I tried changing 'height' to 'padding-top', but that didn't seem to work.

The end result is a web page with a series of 4 black div acting as a border around the edge, it calculates 5% of the with of the window, and that determine's the pixel value for how how the top and bottom black div's are. That way it's exactly even. Now I want my inside wrapper div, to start exactly that far down the web page too.

Comment: More code or jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jQuery outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) function to retrieve the width inclusive of padding, borders and optionally margin as well (if you send true as the only argument to the `outerWidth` method).

Answer (score 0):

Tested Solution: Find height of a div and use it as margin top of another div.

```
$('.topmargindiv').css('margin-top', function() {
    return $('.divheight').height();
});
```